# Unable to start Service after Device Boot Completed. Boot Completed BroadcastReceiver onReceive() not Calling

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, bootcompleted

I am working on one app which will start a service automatically at device start ( after boot complete ). i did code but i think something is going wrong with my code. i have tried google too and all the tricks while research. can you please help me? Thanx in advance.

here is my code :

**My BroadcastReceiver is**

```
public class AutostartReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Booting Completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            //context.startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));
        }
    }
}
```

**My AndroidMenifest file is**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myhiddenapp"
    android:installLocation="internalOnly"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="MyHiddenApp" >
        <receiver
            android:name=".AutostartReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".MyService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Note :** *I have not any Activity, i just want to start Service on Boot Complete.*

Comment: If this is running on an Android version >3.0, you need an Activity that can be launched at least once to bring the app out of the _stopped_ state. Otherwise, your Receiver won't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:installLocation="internalOnly"
    ... >
```

You Must set  android:installLocation="internalOnly"

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html#Should